# manipulating JSON array data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON array from DB, and I want it to manipulate. Currently it has discreet 8 elements, I want the array to manipulate it to get 2 elements, rest elements will be nested. My current JSON has this structure:

```
{
  "itemId": 1,
  "desc": [{
    "type": "A",
    "size": "xx",
    "count": 12,
    "price": 122
  },
  {
    "type": "A",
    "size": "xl",
    "count": 18,
    "price": 180
  },
  {
    "type": "B",
    "size": "xx",
    "count": 12,
    "price": 122
  },
  {
    "type": "B",
    "size": "xl",
    "count": 12,
    "price": 122
  }]
}
```

I want the data to be manipulated to come like this:

```
{
 "type": "A",
  "desc":{
    "size": "xx",
    "count": 12,
    "price": 122
  },
  {
    "size": "xl",
    "count": 12,
    "price": 122
  },
 },
  {
 "type": "B",
  "desc":{
    "size": "xx",
    "count": 12,
    "price": 122
  },
  {
    "size": "xl",
    "count": 12,
    "price": 122
  },
 }
```

I am using for each loop, but this is creating individual elements, i want just two elements in the resulting array.
Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Your desired/output `data-structure/schema` seems to be malformed. Please correct it. Should it be `[{"type": "A", "desc": [{...}, {...}]}, {...}]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var new_data = {
    A: {type: 'A', desc: []},
    B: {type: 'B', desc: []}
};

$.each(data.desc, function( index, value ) {
  new_data[value.type].desc.push(value);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5cnaxn04/

If you don't know the types you will get, you can build the object dynamically:

```
var new_data = {};

$.each(data.desc, function( index, value ) {
  if(typeof new_data[value.type] === "undefined") {
    new_data[value.type] = {type: value.type, desc: [value]}
  } else {
    new_data[value.type].desc.push(value);
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5cnaxn04/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors in your code, as you are using `{}` for both `Array`s and `Object`s, so I'd guess from the context. You need a few loops to make the data look exactly to what you want.

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dz902/cm0sn7ts/).